# Apache .htaccess relative request URI redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, request, relative-path

First of all, I have following directory structure:

- /project_directory/rewriting_experimentation_directory

  - htaccess File
  - realfile.txt

What I am trying to do is following:

When the user requests `http://domain.xts/.../rewriting_experimentation_directory/falsename`,
realfile.txt should be displayed. That I have already achieved, with the following expression in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^falsename$  realfile.txt
```

However, I am also trying to achieve that when the user **requests** this url `http://domain.xts/.../rewriting_experimentation_directory/realfile.txt`,
that he be redirected to `http://domain.xts/.../rewriting_experimentation_directory/falsename` and then, naturally, be displayed the content fo realfile.txt.

I have encountered two issues, however:

1. Firstly, Redirect 301, RedirectMatch, Alias etc. all require
   absolute pathes, and not those relative to the directory the
   .htaccessfile is in. This is completely inacceptable, since the
   path before the directory `rewriting_experimentation_directory` differs from that on localhost when I upload it to domain.xts (or anywhere else)
2. Secondly, it does not match the **requested** URL, but the URL that I shall henceforth refer to as the "**response**" URL, namely the name of the file whose content Apache is returning to the client. Thus, if I try to redirect from realfile.txt to falsename, I get an infinite loop. (Which takes a bit long to load, sadly).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Also, as an answer to the question, 'Why would you need that?' – to learn, for once, and secondly, for future reference (which may still count as learning). I hope that does not invalidate my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this before your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^([A-Z]{3,9})\ (.*)/realfile.txt\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^realfile.txt$ %2/falsename [R=301,L]
```

There's a couple of things that this does, if you simply redirect using RewriteRule (the **R** in the bracket), it will cause a rewrite loop and you'd get an error. You need to check that the *actual request is for "realfile.txt"*. The regular expression, `(.*)/realfile.txt` tries to extract the relative URI, it will be where the .htaccess file resides in (otherwise these conditions/rules won't be exectuted at all), and since we don't know what it is, we can just backreference it using **%2** in the RewriteRule.

So if you place the .htaccess file in `/test/` and request for http://yourdomain/test/realfile.txt you will be 301 redirected to http://yourdomain/test/falsename and your rewrite rule will serve realfile.txt. If you place the .htaccess file in `/deploy/` and request for http://yourdomain/deploy/realfile.txt you will be 301 redirected to http://yourdomain/deploy/falsename, etc.

Comment: This, sir, works perfectly! Still, I have some questions: firstly, what does `^([A-Z]{3,9})\` do? I figure the `^` indicates the start of a regex, and thereafter come 3-9 alphabetic characters. Why 3-9, and why alphabetic? 
Also, what's the use of defining the protocol HTTP at the end of the line?
And why is the result of (.*) referenced via %2, is 2 the number of the regex used?
And what does the L mean at the end of that bracket, and finally: does the RewriteCond only affect the immediate next line, or all rewrite rules?

Comment: Also, if it only affects the next line, how can a condition be made to affect several lines? (Please pardon my curiosity.)

Comment: The first part tries to match the request *METHOD*, which can be **GET**, **POST**, **HEAD**, or a number of other things that go up to 9 letters. If you only really care about 1 or 2 methods, you can change that to `^(GET|HEAD|POST)\ ` or something. As for the %2, [backreferences for RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) uses % instead of $, and we want the 2nd because the first would be the matched method (like **GET**).

Comment: "Also, if it only affects the next line, how can a condition be made to affect several lines? (Please pardon my curiosity.)" - there isn't a way, you'd need to repeat the RewriteCond's. Or you can use the **S** to do something like this: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4239633.htm

Comment: Another question: if, let's say, I had the following request: `/path/to/request/parameters`, with my .htaccess file being located in `request/` (parameters not being a real folder), how could I then display the content of `/path/to/request/?parameters`? That's my current attempt: `RewriteRule ^[.]*$  ?%1`, it doesn't work, though.

Comment: You may want to make another question for that, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do.